# How to delay bind() in onBindViewHolder when the data being bound still is being loaded (needs several more milliseconds to be fully loaded)?

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

```
class TopicListItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ItemTopicListBinding mBinding;

    TopicListItemViewHolder(ItemTopicListBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        mBinding = binding;
    }

    void bind(Topic topic) {
        // get topic attributes, here is where the NPE is thrown because topic is not initiated and so is null
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Topic topic = mTopics.get(position);
    Log.d(TAG, topic.getCreator().getName());
    Log.d(TAG, topic.getCreator().getThumbnailImageUrl());
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case DEFAULT_TOPIC_CARD:
            ((TopicListItemViewHolder) holder).bind(topic);
    }
}
```

So I'm running into an issue where, I retrieve a large chunk of json that gets rendered in a RecyclerView. Occassionally, I get a NullPointerException because in `onBindViewHolder`, part of the `Topic` item is still null when `bind()` is being called, just a few milliseconds too slow). This only happens after the third of fourth `Topic` in the giant json being returned (10 or so total `Topic`s since this is like a home feed).

**I know the issue is due to the fact that deserializing the json into a `Topic` object OR Glide loading the data from imageUrl take too long, just long enough that `onBindViewHolder` is too eager and thus is called on a still being fully initiated `Topic`.**

I'm not sure is there a way for me to delay the `bind` until the `Topic` item currently being bound has fully loaded? I'm using Google's official data binding framework so they must have accounted for issues like this?

Or of course, improve the performance of the deserializing but the json is too complex so I can't.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can initiate the Adapter after the loading is complete.
2. You can pass an empty `ArrayList<Topic>` at the time of initiating the adapter and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after the datas are loaded.